# Rabbitmq connection close abruptly on localhost

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

We have abrupt connection close issue to rabbitmq on localhost dev/testing scenario. In our development environment we have rabbitmq installed on each developers Windows 7 machine, and we connect to it using java client via Spring AMQP library. Everything works fine for a while but at some point of time the connection is dropped with the following message in rabbitmq log:

```
=WARNING REPORT==== 4-Jan-2016::14:39:37 ===
closing AMQP connection <0.3731.0> (127.0.0.1:50792 -> 127.0.0.1:5672):
connection_closed_abruptly
```

In the client log we have this exception:

```
04/01/2016 14:39:37.181 (AMQP Connection 127.0.0.1:5672) ERROR [CachingConnectionFactory] Channel shutdown: connection error
04/01/2016 14:39:38.188 (SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2) WARN  [SimpleMessageListenerContainer] Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it
com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.startShutdown(AMQConnection.java:723)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.shutdown(AMQConnection.java:713)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 0: recv failed
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:254)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedByte(DataInputStream.java:288)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.Frame.readFrom(Frame.java:95)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandler.readFrame(SocketFrameHandler.java:139)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:536)
    ... 1 more
```

In the client start up we create a dynamic queue and attach several consumers to it. This connection drop causes the queue to be removed and any subsequent attempt to recreate it fails with the following exception:

```
04/01/2016 14:39:38.239 (SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-8) WARN  [BlockingQueueConsumer] Queue declaration failed; retries left=3
org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer$DeclarationException: Failed to declare queue(s):[MY_TEST_QU]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:571)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:470)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1165)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:106)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:102)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:124)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:885)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclarePassive(ChannelN.java:61)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:704)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy77.queueDeclarePassive(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:550)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'MY_TEST_QU' in vhost '/', class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:67)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:33)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:361)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:226)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:118)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'MY_TEST_QU' in vhost '/', class-id=50, method-id=10)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:484)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:321)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:144)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:91)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:554)
    ... 1 more
```

We have had this problem with rabbitmq 3.4.x and 3.5.x and Spring AMQP 1.3.x and 1.5.x. The interesting thing is this never happens in our QA and production environment where rabbitmq is installed on a separate server.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.attemptPassiveDeclarations()` fails when there is no the queue to listen to anymore.

It isn't queue `recreation` it is just `PassiveDeclarations`. So, if you drop that "dynamic queue" manually, you should recreate it manually as well.

I mean if you don't follow with the `RabbitAdmin` bean contract, you don't have choice unless re-create it manually. You don't need to worry about the listener in that case: it will reconnect correctly, when the queue comes back.

**UPDATE**

Starting with version `1.5` Spring AMQP provides `ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent`, which is emitted exactly after all `attemptPassiveDeclarations()` attempts. So, you can catch that `ApplicationEvent`, `stop()` your listener container, declare `queue` back and `start()` the container again.

If your queue isn't a bean, it won't be redeclared automatically.

Comment: I have no idea why the connection is dropped but, what @artem is saying is, if you add the queue as a bean and add a `RabbitAdmin` to the context, it will take care of automatically redeclaring the queue for you when the connection is re-established. See [the reference manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp//reference/html/_reference.html#broker-configuration). Alternatively, don't use auto-delete or exclusive queues.

Comment: We use RabbitAdmin to declare the queue but the queue is not a bean. Here is the code `Queue tempQ = new Queue(myQueueName, false, true, true);
        amqpAdmin.declareQueue(tempQ); ` and this code runs in startup.

Comment: Thanks @Artem and @Gary. After some digging around it looks like the connection drop issue to localhost on Windows 7 is related to having both IPv4 and IPv6 enabled on our machines also having `java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` which is required for something else in our application. When I removed java.net.preferIPv4Stack property the connection issue was gone, but we need to keep the property anyway.  So we have to live with the connection problem and fix the dynamic queue access issue.

Comment: As our listener container is a bean writing the code to catch `ApplicationEvent` and stop, declare queue and start is a bit overwhelming. We will go with @Gary's to use auto-delete and exclusive false in queue definition.